# multiline notification in android different behaviour in different device

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, customization, android-notifications

I am trying to display notification text in multiline.

I am using this code to do so.

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    String msg = "Do you want to share Fantasy Cricket on Twitter/FB/Google+?";

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)

    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg).setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Change team");
    mNotificationManager.notify(notId, 123, mBuilder.build());
```

It's displaying differently in two devices.

First device

[image]

Second device

[image]

In first device it just displays fine text in multiline but in second, it's displaying in one line only removing trailing space.

Why it's having different behavior in both. Am I missing something here? Both device are having kitkat if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE**

As per @leo's answer it will display in two line when there is only single notification. But I checked TOI app it's always displaying in two lines.

TOI's screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) say only the top notification is expanded by default. So maybe the other app you are comparing to is using a completely [custom notification layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification) (especially since I don't see a title there)?

Comment: you can see in my code that I am using BigTextStyle. Still it's not working as expected.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone falls into it like me, so according to [LINK](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications)
`Users can drag down on a notification in the drawer to reveal the expanded view, which shows additional content and action buttons, if provided.` This happens often on Samsung devices though...